# custom operator kie workbench

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I have a POJO Class "Dummy" which contains a List of String "nstr".

I am using contains operator "containsItem" as follows :-

rule "DSCR_Rule2"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        Dummy( this containsItem "hi" )
    then
        System.out.println("yes");
end

As per documentation, i have added the evaluator definition in kmodule.xml , and i can compile the project in workbench after a git comit. But operator does not show up in guided editor even after a tomcat restart. What am i missing ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the standard operator `contains` or the `contains()` method?

Comment: Hi Laune, my use case is more complex.. quite similar to the containsItem operator mentioned in the Packt Drools guide 6 . For now im basically trying to get into workbench the operator that's mentioned in the book. I'm able to register and use it it in an eclipse drool project, but the kie workbench just  won't show it .

Comment: It must be possible to implement it as a method for class Dummy, which is yet another option you have and which I didn't mention in my first comment.